# How to find all woocommerce products, simple and Variable, with 0 stock value and change in stock to out of stock

Tags: woocommerce

I have previously bulk edited all my woocommerce products to show 'in stock' even though the stock was 0, this was to enable me to sell the products on backorder.

I now realise that was a mistake.

I now need to change the 0 value Products from 'in stock' to 'out of stock'

I have access to the sql database